# Homepage divided layout (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I want to create this homepage for my site which only accepts add-ons of html/css without retouching any other rule.

Only achieved making the blocks themselves but no clue on how to put images behind the buttons,center everything up and make it responsive...

Any tip?

[Homepage intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SBVt.jpg)
page link: www.lluisballbe.smugmug.com

Code used already is here:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
}

#business-top {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background:turquoise;
}

#business-button {
  height: 3em;
  width: 12em;
  background-color: #2B2A2A;
  border: .2em solid #ff7600;
  border-radius: 1.8em;
  margin: auto;
}

#logo-separator {
  text-align: center;
}

.separator {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 1px;
  line-height: 0;
  flex: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ff7600;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff7600;
}

#logo {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: -75px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
}

#photography-bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background:gray;
}

#photography-button {
  height: 3em;
  width: 12em;
  background-color: #2B2A2A;
  border: .2em solid #ff7600;
  border-radius: 1.8em;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  color: #ff7600;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 2.2em
}

#business-top,
#photography-bottom {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: 1s;
  min-height: 200px;
}

#business-top a,
#photography-bottom a {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

#business-top:hover,
#photography-bottom:hover {
  flex: 3;
}

#business-top a:hover:before,
#photography-bottom a:hover:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="business-top">
  <a href="www.lluisballbe.smugmug.com">
    <div id="business-button">
      <h1>BUSINESS</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<div id="logo-separator">
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div id="logo"><img src="https://lluisballbe.smugmug.com/Assets-for-website/i-CsMnM3R/0/Th/800x800-round-Th.png"> </div>
</div>

<div id="photography-bottom">
  <a href="www.lluisballbe.smugmug.com">
    <div id="photography-button">
      <h1>PHOTOGRAPHY</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Images to be used (each should cover 50%, can resize them and change pixel size if needed):
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54898895/Public.rar
[Top Image][3]

[Bottom image][4]

Comment: Do you have the link of the images ?

Comment: What does *"which only accepts add-ons of html/css without retouching any other rule"* mean?

Comment: Could you please reword your question in a more precise manner? The above appears a little like "I have no idea how this all works, please do it for me" which is nothing we can answer to...

Comment: Sure, changing it now! Sorry about it! Images added

Comment: @Paulie_D, it has its own rules for layout and style on it and lets add "blocks" of Html that you can edit with CSS, but no edit on full page like say body {} whatsoever. The client I run is Smugmug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

1. Add `height: 50vh;` to `#business-top` and `#photography-bottom` for both outter container.
2. Give your containers your custom background-images: `background-image: url('url to image');`
3. Make sure the images have `background-size: cover;`
4. Add your `#logo-separator` with `position:absolute;` 
   and `top: calc( 50% - (height_of_sperator)px;`

Comment: Yeah! That Worked! :D Figuring out now how to put the images in there but one thing, the background image will be affected by the size of it or it will be only 50vh always as child of container? Thanks!

Comment: good. the background images will be as big as the container if you use: `background-size:100%`

Comment: Great! It looks awesome and just as intended :) Thank you so much!

Comment: nice that I could help you

Comment: Hmmm, just found something rare here... See what happens in responsive...[link] https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54898895/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202016-02-16%2014.45.24.png I guess that since the height of the picture doesn't cover the full screen it multiplies it. Could that be it?

Comment: ` background-size: cover;` will make it responsive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103612/discussion-between-dr-debug-and-luiggi19).